# change Paypal email on a button

Tags: php, paypal

I'm selling a certain product on my page. I got a button ID that holds all the information of the sale (Paypal account to transfer the money to, price, return URL, etc) and I use this button to get my money from people.

What I want is to be able to make it so that every purchase through this page goes to a friend's Paypal account. now, I can ask him to make a button and give me the button ID, but then I wont be able to control the price and return URL and such data (he might change them on his own).

I'm looking for a solution where I can just change the Paypal email account of the receiver on my page and viola.

Is there such thing? (In the safest way possible of course)
Thanks

Comment: Didnt i anwer your question? you should mark as answered

Comment: you're right, sorry, i haven't noticed. fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So open up your button code in a text-editor and change the value here and viola

```
<input name="business" type="hidden" value="change this to the email">
```

Note ** 
You will find a full list of the html variables and their details for the paypal standard buttons

@https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/